# UIPickerView DataSource x Delegate Design

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, uipickerview

I find really strange, or a bad design decision, that `UIPickerViewDelegate` contains methods that need to be aware of its data (title). As that would be the whole purpose of its `DataSource`. Like these:

```
pickerView(_:titleForRow:forComponent:)
pickerView(_:attributedTitleForRow:forComponent:)
pickerView(_:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView:)
```

I want to implement a `PickerView` with different objects for `DataSource` and `Delegate`. Sure, it'd be easy enough to create a new delegate, maybe call it `PickerViewListenerDelegate`. But as apple had made this design decision I thought it's worth a discussion first.

What is the point of this weird design decision? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

The `UIPickerViewDataSource` protocol only addresses direct properties of the data source, i.e. the number of components and number of rows in each of those.

The `UIPickerViewDelegate` protocol adresses the presentation. It provides the sizes, titles or views, and the callback for selection changes.

If we compare that with `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate`, the pattern oddly is quite different.

Often enough, both `delegate` and `dataSource` get wired up to the same object, i.e. a view controller, that routes the calls to the underlying model and constructs the needed UI elements. And personally, I think that wiring the dataSource to the data model, but the delegate to the controller - makes a weird decision that can easily break encapsulation.

So basically it means: yes, you can separate between model and presentation (i.e. formatter) here using the given pattern. If you find it useful, is up to you.

Comment: Just like with Table Views, I do often use the same Controller object as DataSource and Delegate. However, as I see it, they're 2 different properties for a reason, and this one time it would make sense for my design to use two different objects, however, the weird design of `UIPickerViewDataSource` and `UIPickerViewDelegate` prevents me from doing that. (I would have to link them in odd ways so the `delegate` knows the titles.